# Java: JTable reordering rows and refresh

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I have a `JTable` (extended) and an implementation of `TableModel`, in which I have the methods ...

- `moveEntryUp(int rowIdx)`
- `moveEntryDown(int rowIdx)`

... within the table model implementation. I have verified that these work properly.

However, I am having problems in getting the changes made in the table model to propagate to the actual `JTable`. In this table I only allow single row selection, and have seperate button for **Up** and **Down**. When a row is elected, I need to be able to move that row up and down, *and* preserve the selection.

E.g.
If my rows are `[A, B, C(selected)]`, and I press the up button,
I should get `[A, C(selected), B]`.

The various approaches I have tried so far either fail to refresh the values in the JTable, or lose the selection.

---

NOTE:
I am hesitant to use a solution which requires an explicit call to `repaint()`.
Assume that all cells in the `JTable` are *not* editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering own question:

```
int row = mTable.getSelectedRow();
mTableModel.moveEntryUp(row);
mTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(row -1, row -1);
```

Where `mTable` is the JTable, and `mTableModel` is my table model implementation, and is equivalent to `mTable.getModel()` (and typecast).

Should've poked around longer before asking!